# How to access relation ID after saving in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have many-to-many relation between two models: `movie` and `actor`.

I need to obtain relation ID after saving it, to use it later. Here's the code:

```
$movie->actors()->save($actor); // it saves my relation
$relationID = 'how to obtain ID of new record in pivot table?';
```

Comment: What does `$movie->actors()->save($actor);` return?

Comment: It returns $actor model with no access to pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

In Movie model:

```
public function actors() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Actor')
                ->withPivot('id');
}
```

And I obtained ID this way:

```
$relationID = $movie->actors()
                    ->where('actor.id', $actor->id)
                    ->first()->pivot->id;
```

Ugly, but works. If it can be done any better, please let me know. :)